# MySQL Group By With Case Order

Tags: mysql

I need to group only certain rows together. Specifically, anything that is the Shipping product category needs to be grouped together by their item number. My query is:

```
SELECT
            
            imcatfil_sql.prod_cat,
            imitmidx_sql.item_no
        FROM
            estimate
        JOIN 
            imitmidx_sql ON estimate.item_no=imitmidx_sql.item_no 
        JOIN 
            imcatfil_sql ON imitmidx_sql.prod_cat=imcatfil_sql.prod_cat
        WHERE
            budget_header_id=19303 AND (deleted_by_id=0 OR deleted_by_id IS NULL) AND estimate.item_no NOT IN('157','156','158') AND hidden=0 AND item_desc_1 NOT LIKE '%SALES TAX%' 
        GROUP BY CASE WHEN imitmidx_sql.prod_cat='200' THEN estimate.item_no ELSE RAND() END;
        ORDER BY
            imcatfil_sql.prod_cat,imitmidx_sql.user_def_fld_3,estimate.id;
```

While everything with a prod_cat of 200 is grouped together by item_no, everything else is not in prod_cat order as specified by my ORDER BY. I suspect it's because of the ELSE RAND(). So, I took that out. What I wind up with is prod_cat 200 (i.e. Shipping) working properly but I get back a single row for everything else.

Answer (score 0):

How about splitting it into two queries with a UNION ALL (I'm assuming that the prod_cat and item_no will already be distinct?

So something like...

```
SELECT
    imcatfil_sql.prod_cat,
    imitmidx_sql.item_no
FROM
    estimate
JOIN 
    imitmidx_sql ON estimate.item_no=imitmidx_sql.item_no 
JOIN 
    imcatfil_sql ON imitmidx_sql.prod_cat=imcatfil_sql.prod_cat
WHERE
    budget_header_id=19303 
    AND (deleted_by_id=0 OR deleted_by_id IS NULL) 
    AND estimate.item_no NOT IN('157','156','158') 
    AND hidden=0 
    AND item_desc_1 NOT LIKE '%SALES TAX%' 
    AND imitmidx_sql.prod_cat='200'
GROUP BY 
    estimate.item_no
UNION ALL
SELECT
    imcatfil_sql.prod_cat,
    imitmidx_sql.item_no
FROM
    estimate
JOIN 
    imitmidx_sql ON estimate.item_no=imitmidx_sql.item_no 
JOIN 
    imcatfil_sql ON imitmidx_sql.prod_cat=imcatfil_sql.prod_cat
WHERE
    budget_header_id=19303 
    AND (deleted_by_id=0 OR deleted_by_id IS NULL) 
    AND estimate.item_no NOT IN('157','156','158') 
    AND hidden=0 
    AND item_desc_1 NOT LIKE '%SALES TAX%' 
    AND imitmidx_sql.prod_cat <> '200'
ORDER BY
    imcatfil_sql.prod_cat
    ,imitmidx_sql.user_def_fld_3
    ,estimate.id;
```

If the overall ordering is important then you can always wrap another select around this and move the order by into that.

Comment: I tried the UNION query and got this error: Table 'imcatfil_sql' from one of the SELECTs cannot be used in field list. Not sure why I'm getting that error.

Comment: @FloydResler Make sure you have the same number of columns being returned and the same data type for each column position. If you don't need the same number of columns, just select NULL in place of each missing column.